# Which type to use when iterating a std::vector (without iterators)?

Tags: c++

Perhaps this question is trivial, but thinking a second time about it I wonder how to do the following really the right way:

```
std::vector<K> v = ...;
for(T i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) {
  const K& t = v[i];
  // use t *and i*
}
```

What type should `T` be? `int`, `unsigned int`, `int32_t`, `size_t` (which would be the type of `v.size()`) or any other suggestions? Please try to consider portability, error-proneness and performance and be objective in your answer.

**Edit:** I did not choose iterators, because it would also like to use the index number i explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `i` should be the same as the return value of `size()`, which is `std::vector<K>::size_type`. However, in practice, `size_t` will do just fine. If you use a *signed* integer type, then your compiler will probably warn about a signed/unsigned mismatch in the less-than comparison.

Normally you would use an iterator for this anyway:

```
std::vector<K> v = ...;
for (std::vector<K>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
  const K& t = *i;
  // use t
}
```

Or, in C++0x:

```
std::vector<K> v = ...;
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
  const K& t = *i;
  // use t
}
```

In response to your comment about using the vector index with iterators, consider the `std::distance()` function which is constant time operation for vector iterators:

```
std::vector<K> v = ...;
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
  const K& t = *i;
  size_t index = std::distance(v.begin(), i);
  // use t and index
}
```

Comment: Or, in C++0x: `for (auto i:v) { .. }` (N2930) :-)

Comment: Now my question would be, what is faster/clearer/portable: using an integer to iterate (and having it as index directly) or using an iterator and the distance function to compute the index?

Comment: @Danvil: most likely, it doesn't matter. Both consist of a simple increment and either an add or a subtract. And in both cases, those two statements cannot be parallized. I expect that the solution to increment both i and the iterator separately will be slightly faster as it can be parallized. However, I doubt the difference is measurable in practice.

Answer (score 3):

The type returned by `v.size` and expected by `v[]` is `std::vector<K>::size_type`.

However, consider using iterators instead : the risk of going out of bounds is lower, and you can use the standard library algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

The type T usually doesn't matter as long as it is as large as the vector size.

In terms of performance, there should't be any differences.

In terms of error-proneness/portability, I suggest using signed integers, because if you somehow *subtract* values from `i`, you'll get a large positive number, which is harder to check than a negative number. But because `v.size()` is a `size_t`, if you use a signed integer for T, and `v` has ≥ 2<sup>31</sup> (or 2<sup>63</sup>) items, the `i` will have to become invalid before ending. But I think if the vector needs to be that ridiculously large (esp. on 64-bit platforms), there is other a bigger problem than which type T to choose.

Never use `int32_t` for a counter.

---

(These are before OP's edit:)

But in your case you may want iterate with an iterator instead.

```
for (std::vector<K>::const_iterator cit = v.begin(); cit != v.end(); ++ cit) {
  const K& t = *cit;
  // ...
}
```

With [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/foreach.html) you could turn this mess into

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const K& t, v) {
  // ...
}
```

In C++0x this becomes a [built-in feature](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/foreach.html) (§[stmt.ranged]), but AFAIK no compilers supported it yet:

```
for (const K& t : v) {
  // ...
}
```

But most compilers that claim to support C++0x should allow `auto`:

```
for (auto cit = v.cbegin(); cit != v.cend(); ++ cit) {
   const K& t = *cit;
   // ...
}
```

or lambda expression:

```
std::for_each(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](const K& t) { 
   ...
});
```

Comment: And how to know the position of the element in theses cases? Do you thing that iterators and extra counting are better than using a number to iterate?

Comment: @Danvil: Usually I'll keep 2 variables, the counter and the iterator. This is needed if you want to traverse non-vector structures. But for vectors, `t = v[i]` and `i = distance(cit, begin)` have similar performance, and both involve only pointer arithmetic and bit shifts.

Comment: If I would use int as iterator type, considering the fact, that size() is size_t which is usually unsigned, isn't it slower to compare signed to unsigned integers? Additionally the compiler prduces one of these annoying warnings about comparing signed to unsigned integers.

Comment: I would expect ++i, ++cit to be slightly faster as it is parallizable by the CPU.

Comment: @Danvil: On x86-64, g++ 4.2, comparing unsigned with signed or unsigned makes no difference. Comparing signed with signed use 2 less opcodes.